# Hardy space on unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ and Hardy space on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$

Tags: complex-analysis, hardy-spaces

I am studying Hardy space on the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}$ recently.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy_space) says that 
there is a isometic isomorphism between Hardy space on the upper half plane  and Hardy space on the unit disk $M$:$H^2(\mathbb{H}) \rightarrow H^2(\mathbb{D})$ by the following map:
$$(Mf)(z)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{1-z}f(i\frac{1+z}{1-z})$$

By change of variables, I can check that $M$ is an isometric and isomorphism between $L^2(\mathbb{H})$ and $L^2(\mathbb{D})$.But I can not prove $M$ is an isometric isomorphism between Hardy spaces.

Any help would be appreciated!